# Change in application.js can not take effect in rails 3.1.3 with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

We just found something strange with our rails 3.1.3 app's application.js. The problem is that even we purposely change the code from right to wrong in application.js, the right code (before change) is still executed. The change in application.js does not change the behavior of app at all. It seems that the application.js has been frozen and can not be modified. Any suggestion how to fix this problem? thanks so much.

Comment: do you use the asset pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using the asset pipeline you may need to:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: After deleted all application.* in public/assets the applicatoin.js work as expected.

Comment: One more question, when to rake assets:precompile? Thanks.

Comment: @user938363 You probably ran the precompilation task once in development and forgot about it, which is why those files were taking precedence over your app/assets files. In development you shouldn't normally even have a public/assets directory. The precompilation task should be run during deployments on the application server(s) and not locally.

Comment: I don't know the official answer to be honest, I find I have to every time I update an asset